# Pass image to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good morning,
I am trying to pass an image from one page to another and having some difficulty. The page its is on is called Spain.aspx, it show Spanish football jerseys, it has a images in a gridview, i want users to be able to click on this any jersey and get redirected to a page called ProductLarge where it will display the jersey they clicked and show it on a much larger scale. I have read around and tried some different methods but the closet i seem to be is with the below code:

```
<asp:Image ID="productimage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/Handler.ashx?productid=" + Eval("productid")%>' Width="100" Height="100" />
```

or

```
<asp:HyperLink Font-Size="12px" ID="lnkImage" runat="server" 
ImageUrl='<%# "~/Handler.ashx?productid=" + Eval("productid")%>'
NavigateUrl='<%#"ProductLarge.aspx?productid=" + Eval("productid")%>'>
<a href ="ProductLarge.aspx" > </a> </asp:HyperLink>
```

Would anyone have advice, being new to this should i use a Handler(in your opinion), or be trying to use alternative methods for passing an image? Any help appreciated,

Comment: How is the image stored in the db. As an image (blob) or as a path?

Answer (score 0):

You can send images' ID by query string then retrieve this ID from DB

Comment: if you want that users to able see large image,you can use LightBox(http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)